# LiveData.observeAsState not working in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a Viewmodel in jetpack compsoe using offical video here:

[Jetpack Compose: State](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mymWGMy9pYI)

It shows this minimal exmaple:

```
class HelloViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _name = MutableLiveData("")
    val name: LiveData<String> = _name

    fun onNameChange(newName: String) {
        _name.value = newName
    }
}

@Composable
fun HelloScreen(helloViewModel: HelloViewModel = HelloViewModel()) {
    val name: String by helloViewModel.name.observeAsState("")
    HelloContent(name = name, onNameChange = { helloViewModel.onNameChange(it) })
}

@Composable
fun HelloContent(name: String, onNameChange: (String) -> Unit) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        if (name.isNotEmpty()) {
            Text(
                text = "Hello, $name!",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
            )
        }
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = name,
            onValueChange = onNameChange,
            label = { Text("Name") }
        )
    }
}
```

after updating to Jetpack Compose version 1.1.0 I can't write any char, it removed Immediately after inserted, anyone knows for a workaround please,
Thank in advance,

Comment: You're creating a new view model on each recomposition here: `helloViewModel: HelloViewModel = HelloViewModel()`. It should be `helloViewModel: HelloViewModel = viewModel()`. Have you copied this code from somewhere? In this case it should be reported.

Comment: Thank you Philip,
it fixes my problems,
I had to add that dependency:
```implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.1"```
and afterwards do your recommendation
and than everything works!

Comment: This code is pretty similiar (not to say the same) to this official Google video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mymWGMy9pYI&t=167s

Comment: That what I've written in the first 2 lines of the post

Answer (score 1):

[LiveData.observeAsState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/livedata/package-summary#(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData).observeAsState(kotlin.Any)) is an extension method that is part of the [androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata) library.

You have to add this library to your app's dependencies, as follows:

```groovy
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.6.0")
}
```